# NavigateToViewModel with Caliburn Micro 2 and Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: caliburn.micro, windows-phone-8.1

I'm trying to figure out how to successfully get Caliburn Micro to navigate from one page to another in a Windows Phone 8.1 app.

My first page loads just fine, as specified in my App class:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    this.DisplayRootViewFor<HomeViewModel>();
}
```

This launches the HomeView without issue. On that view I have a button that calls the following method:

```
public void GoToPage2()
{
    this.navigationService.NavigateToViewModel<Page2ViewModel>();
}
```

This method is called when the button is pressed and the constructor for Page2ViewModel is called as well. The page just never displays and I can't figure out why. I feel like I'm missing a core concept, but I can't find any examples of how this should work.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Have you read this article? http://wp.qmatteoq.com/using-caliburn-micro-with-universal-windows-app-navigation/

Comment: I have and while it is informative, it doesn't solve my problem. I have a view model that inherits from Screen and it is instantiated and OnActivate is called. It's just that the view never appears on the screen.

Comment: Do you have a Page2View?

Comment: Yes, I have a Page2View. See my answer below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is odd, and perhaps a bug in Caliburn Micro. In the OnLaunched method I used to have:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    this.DisplayRootViewFor<HomeViewModel>();
}
```

This worked and launched the home view, but subsequent navigation never worked. After comparing to a sample application I found, I changed the code to:

```
protected override void OnLaunched(LaunchActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    this.DisplayRootView<HomeView>();
}
```

This also displays the home view, but now subsequent navigation works! I'm not sure why this would be the case, but at least I have an answer.

Comment: Actually not a bug, it's a result of view-first vs viewmodel first development. They slightly different in design and if you using straight wp8.1 non-Silverlight variant.

Comment: @mvermef: It's definitely a bug. Bugs are not just about coding: misleading design or obscure intention are bugs as well.

Comment: https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/71 if you really want to say something with respect to the issue there ya go.  Docs do need updating related to this design methodology related to view-first vs viewmodel first, it represents no bug, but difference of opinion.